# Pegar valores de input

Tags: javascript

Olá! Em meu código, eu tenho 12 inputs. Quando eu clicar num determinado botão, eu preciso verificar qual desses inputs tem alguma coisa escrita e guardar esse valor em uma única array. O que eu não estou conseguindo fazer, é guardar todos esses valores em uma única array.
HTML:

```
<div class="inputsParticipantes">
        <h3>Quais são os nomes dos participantes ?</h3>
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <button class="comecar btn">Começar</button>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var $players = document.querySelectorAll('.inputPlayers');
  var $comecar = document.querySelector('.comecar');

  $comecar.addEventListener('click', jogar)

  function jogar(){
     var x = 0;
     while($players[x]){
        if($players[x].value.length >= 1){
        guardarValorInputs($players[x]) 
        }
        x++;
    }

    function guardarValorInputs(inputs){
    var valor = inputs.value;
    var arrValorInput = valor.split();
    console.log(arrValorInput);
}
```

Comment: Por que o `x++` não fica drentro do `while`?

Comment: Mas ele está dentro do while

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var players = document.querySelectorAll('.inputPlayers');
var comecar = document.querySelector('.comecar');
comecar.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  var a = [];
  /* Guardando resultados no array */
  players.forEach(function(e) {
      if ( e.value != "" )
      a.push(e.value);
  });

  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)));
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="inputsParticipantes">
        <h3>Quais são os nomes dos participantes ?</h3>
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <input type="text" class="inputPlayers">
        <button class="comecar btn">Começar</button>
</div>
```